# Angular ERROR TS2341: Property 'X' is private and only accessible within class

Tags: angular, service

I'm doing an exercise code from an angular course.

The app works but I have this error in my mac terminal, I'm doing it exactly as the course shows, can't find what's wrong.

```
Error: src/app/components/articles/articles.component.html:1:22 - error TS2341: Property 'articles' is private and only accessible within class 'ArticlesComponent'.

1 <h3>Repositorios : {{articles.articlesCount}}</h3>
```

Here es my service:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {
    public articlesCount : number = 30;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public getAll(){
            this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/codigofacilito/repos').subscribe(data=> {
            console.log(data);
    })
}}
```

Heres is the article.component who consumes the service:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ArticleService} from '../../services/article.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-articles',
  templateUrl: './articles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./articles.component.css']
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private articles : ArticleService) { }

    ngOnInit(){
      this.articles.getAll();
    }

}
```

And the view HTML:

```html
<h3>Repositorios : {{articles.articlesCount}}</h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare a public property in the class to be able to use it in the template

`articles` refers to a service injected privately, so it cannot be accessed from the component template, and it is a service instance and you cannot use it to store articles in. you should use a different variable for that purpose.

you can declare a public property `allArticles` in your `ArticlesComponent` component, assign to it the result from your service, and this way it can be accessed from the template.

you can do this way:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {ArticleService} from '../../services/article.service';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-articles',
      templateUrl: './articles.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./articles.component.css']
    })
    export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {
        public allArticles;
        
        constructor(private articles : ArticleService) { }

        ngOnInit(){
          this.articles.getAll().subscribe( results => {
            this.allArticles = results;
          });
        }

    }
```

in the template:

```html
<h3>Repositorios : {{allArticles.articlesCount}}</h3>
```

In your service `getAll()` should return an `Observable`

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {
  public articlesCount : number = 30;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/codigofacilito/repos');
  }
}
```

in your `ArticleService`, you have to remove the subscribe in `getAll()` as well

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, it works ! ... I still have doubts on how services works, even 
though my terminal throws error, the app still works as I showed on my first post. As im seeing in the explanation it should be no need to create the variable in the component... maybe its an old course idk... im a bit confused

Comment: I can also declare 'acrticlesCount : number'; and inicate it in the component like 'this.articlesCount = 30' get the same error but the app still works and showing the value correctly :S

Answer (score 0):

HTML templates can access variables defined in the `component` files.

> You have not provided the `articles` variable in the `article.component.ts`

Do below changes :

```
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {

public articles: any; // provide correct type 
constructor(private articleService : ArticleService) { }

ngOnInit(){
    this.articleService.getAll().subscribe((result)=>{
       this.articles = result
   })
}

}
```

and in the service file :

```
 public getAll(){
       return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/codigofacilito/repos')
}
```

Comment: You are mixing `private articles` injected service with `public articles` that you assume to be another variable, but they have the same name. This cannot work.

Comment: @hdjemai thanks for pointing out. I didn't notice that.. but still my answer is right :)

Comment: you can't assign `results` to `this.articles` because `this.articles` was a service instance before your fix, so it was not that right.